Getting error " application installation failed " in android studio while using it with kotlin
I have just started with kotlin in android studio, and i am constantly getting encountered by error "The Device already has newer version of this application. In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application". But here i didn't have the same application already in my cell phone. I have the older apps i have created using java.
I have tried changing the version code and version name but can't getting it to the right way.

And this still occurs after you uninstalled the app from the device?

Yes i have uninstalled all the apps build with Android studio in my android device.
